# OKTA AWS CLI Using Python to Connect to Athena

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-athena, okta

My company uses Okta Authentication for all corporate applications. Is there a way or a workaround to circumvent the OKTA Authentication while connecting to AWS Athena? I'm trying to automate a Python Script that connects to Athena and it requires me to Okta Verify every time after the short-lived token expires. However, Google Suite (Docs, Sheets, Drive) API's doesn't require this type of AUTH verification method and it never requests one when I connect Python to Google Suites although our Google Suite use Okta Authentication for login.

Any help or references would be much appreciated. Thank you!